# Code for userform (spinner) returning type mismatch if lots of cells selected. VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, range, spinner

I understand that type mismatch is usually when you define a variable incorrectly but I am not sure that makes sense in this case. My code, posted below, is for a userform that has a spinner on it and cells you highlight prior to clicking on the userform are increased/decreased by a specified % when you click on the spinner buttons.

This works perfectly for a lower number of cells. So I can select 5 different ranges of 4 cells each for example and it will behave as intended however when I select more than this I get a type mismatch error when I use the spinner and the debugger highlights the singlecell.Value = singlecell.Value * pvar code in the below. This only seems to impact the last few rows of each range selected.

Does anyone know why this is or how to rectify the situation? With my limited knowledge it seems not entirely to make sense as a type mismatch error. My only assumption is that when defining AS Range there is a limit to the amount that can be stored as a range? Please see code below:

'code for opening sinner userform

```
Public SelRange As Range
Public pvar As Double
Public SelVar As Double
Public InitVar As Double
Public GetAllValuesAtOnceAsArray As Variant

Sub Button2_Click()
Spinner.Show
End Sub
```

'Code for Userform

```
Option Explicit

'on opening userform this sets the variables

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

pvar = 1
Set SelRange = Selection
GetAllValuesAtOnceAsArray = SelRange.Value

End Sub

'button to maintain adjusted values

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm3.Show

End Sub

'Button to return to starting values

Private Sub DefaultButton_Click()

Dim singlecell As Range

'write back the original values
SelRange.Value = GetAllValuesAtOnceAsArray

'Adjust every single Cell within range
pvar = 1

End Sub

'Spin Up button

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

pvar = pvar + UpBox.Value / 100

'write back the original values
SelRange.Value = GetAllValuesAtOnceAsArray

Dim singlecell As Range

'Adjust every single Cell within range
For Each singlecell In SelRange.Cells
    singlecell.Value = singlecell.Value * pvar
Next singlecell


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

' Spin Down button

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()

pvar = pvar - DownBox.Value / 100

'write back the original values
SelRange.Value = GetAllValuesAtOnceAsArray

Dim singlecell As Range

'Adjust every single Cell within range
For Each singlecell In SelRange.Cells
        singlecell.Value = singlecell.Value * pvar
Next singlecell

End Sub

' Reset values when closing userform unless specified otherwise

Private Sub UserForm_terminate()

'Now write back the original values
SelRange.Value = GetAllValuesAtOnceAsArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the ranges that you select noncontiguous?

Comment: Also -- *when* do you get the error? Is it when the form loads or when you hit the spin button?

Comment: If you get the error at `singlecell.Value = singlecell.Value * pvar` then why don't you just insert a checker to confirm what you think like this `if IsNumeric(singlecell.value) then` and in the `else` part I would put something like this `debug.print singlecell.address & " is not a number"`.

Comment: Hi John, they are usually non-contiguous and the error arises when I click the spin button as opposed to opening the userform.

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks for the advice and it is the case that the cells that are giving errors are not numbers. Why would this happen to some and not others though when they are identically defined? It doesn't seem to discriminate in any way I can see a pattern to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you "selected 5 different ranges of 4 cells each" which seems to suggest that you are selecting noncontiguous ranges. If that is the case then maybe the real problem is the way you try to store and then restore the values in the range in a variant array. It doesn't work that way. Consider the following sub:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim myRange As Range, myCopy As Variant
    Set myRange = Selection
    myCopy = myRange.Value
    myRange.ClearContents
    'now restore:
    myRange.Value = myCopy 'doesn't always work!
End Sub
```

Fill the ranges A1:B2 and D1:E4 with various values and then simultaneously select them by first selecting A1:B2 and then D1:E4. Invoke the sub. You should see #N/A in range D3:E4 -- which is what causes the actual type mismatch.

The problem is that noncontiguous ranges are collections of areas, and only the first area is grabbed by the Value property. If you really want to store and then restore values you could do something like the following:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim myRange As Range, myArea As Range
    Dim myCopy As Variant
    Dim i As Long, numAreas As Long

    Set myRange = Selection

    numAreas = myRange.Areas.Count
    If numAreas = 1 Then
        myCopy = myRange.Value
    Else
        ReDim myCopy(1 To numAreas)
        For i = 1 To numAreas
            myCopy(i) = myRange.Areas(i).Value
        Next i
    End If

    myRange.ClearContents

    'now restore:

    If numAreas = 1 Then
        myRange.Value = myCopy
    Else
        For i = 1 To numAreas
            myRange.Areas(i).Value = myCopy(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

In your case you would probably want to have myCopy and numAreas module-level variables. Both The code for copying values and the code for restoring values can be moved to subs, as well as the code for multiplying each cell in a range by a value (useful for both spinup and spindown) This is illustrated by the following 3 subs, followed by a test sub to show how the sub calls work:

```
Sub CopyVals(R As Range, V As Variant)
    Dim A As Range
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = R.Areas.Count
    If n = 1 Then
        V = R.Value
    Else
        ReDim V(1 To n)
        For i = 1 To n
            V(i) = R.Areas(i).Value
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Sub RestoreVals(R As Range, V As Variant)
    Dim A As Range
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = R.Areas.Count
    If n = 1 Then
        R.Value = V
    Else
        For i = 1 To n
            R.Areas(i).Value = V(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Sub Multiply(R As Range, p As Double)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In R.Cells
        c.Value = p * c.Value
    Next c
End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim myRange As Range, myCopy As Variant
    Dim pvar As Double

    Set myRange = Selection
    CopyVals myRange, myCopy
    pvar = 0.9
    Multiply myRange, pvar

    pvar = 1.1
    RestoreVals myRange, myCopy
    Multiply myRange, pvar
End Sub
```

Note that the last two lines of test() *can't* be collapsed to

```
RestoreVals myRange, myCopy * pvar
```

Since that would involve an array times a double type mismatch

Comment: The issue I have now is that I need to replace the contents of the cells with the previous contents of the cells times a % implied by the spinner however if I use the following code: 

If numAreas = 1 Then
        myRange.Value = myCopy * pvar
    Else
        For i = 1 To numAreas
            myRange.Areas(i).Value = myCopy(i) * pvar
        Next i
    End If

which is essentially your code but with mycopy * pvar (stands for percentage variable) I get another type mismatch.

Comment: @Sam I guess I don't understand the motivation -- if the spin button has already modified those values why do you need to recopy the original values just to remodify them? Perhaps have  a Boolean variable control whether or not the terminate events recopies. In any event, myCopy or myCopy(i) (as the case may be) would be *arrays* (except in the special case that the area consisted of a single cell) and it makes no sense to multiply an array by a scalar value. If you want to go this route - just recopy the values then later loop over the cells, modifying the values.

Comment: @Sam Also -- the copy code and the restore code (if you are going to use them a lot) could be fruitfully moved into subs (say CopySelection() and RestoreSelection()) to make the rest of the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks again. Just to explain. The spreadsheet has a load of values (for example asset prices). Then, in theory but not functionally, the user can select whatever assets they want to and then apply the spinner, this mimics an increase/decrease of a % in the price of those assets etc and then they can observe how this impacts various aspects of the business. Then they have two buttons, one that can keep the adjusted values and another to reset the values.

Comment: also...the original values will be set to what is expected to happen but the ability to be able to change these assumptions to assess the impact is key however in a lot of cases we will want to see the impact but not maintain it in the spreadsheet. I am not great with VBA so would you be able to explain or give an example of how you would suggest I copy and loop back over the cells? Thanks.

Comment: That is really helpful thanks, I have now got that to work. Just one question left, is it possible to make this work in cells across multiple tabs?

Comment: By "tabs" I think you mean "worksheets". If so the short answer is "no" -- range variables can only refer to ranges on a specific sheet (since Range is a child of Worksheet in the Excel object model). There is a long answer that you might prefer, but comments are not the place to discuss it. Ask another question e.g. "Modify a userform to work on multiple sheets" (though you should search Stack Overflow a bit first to make sure it isn't a duplicate). By the way -- by convention don't include the tag in the title of the question itself the way you did for this one.